# MATCH AGAINST in Doctrine

Tags: php, parameters, doctrine, match, against

I found that if I use MATCH AGAINST in Doctrine with WHERE syntax does not replace the parameters passed. For example if I run the following code
$

```
q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('*')
    ->from('TourismUnit tu')
    ->where('FALSE');
if ($keywords) {
    $keywords_array = $this->parse_keywords($keywords);
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($keywords_array); $i++)
        $q->orWhere("MATCH (name, description) AGAINST ('?*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)", $keywords_array[$i]);
}
```

does not find any results.
And if they use the string concatenation seems to work.

```
 $q->orWhere("MATCH (name, description) AGAINST ('".$keywords_array[$i]."*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
```

I use Doctrine 1.2.2.

Does anyone know why not replace the parameters before executing the sql expression?

Comment: the use of single quote seems causing the problem - does this `concat("'", ?, "*'")` help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the use of single quote causing the problem,
convert it to use `concat("'", ?, "*'")`

Answer (score 2):

In prepared statements as above, the **placeholder doesn't like quotes** [as shown in the doctrine manual.](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html)

So you could simply write:

```
$q->orWhere("MATCH (name, description) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", $keywords_array[$i].'*');
```