# How To Use MATCH In Symfony2 Database Query

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm building a search feature for my Symfony2 project, and I wrote the SQL for it as follows:

```
SELECT dlc.title, dlc.description, dlc.keywords
FROM ShoutMainBundle:Dlc dlc
WHERE MATCH (dlc.title, dlc.description, dlc.keywords) AGAINST (":keyword" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND dlc.type = (":audio")
ORDER BY dlc.date DESC
```

However, when I run this in the project the following error is given:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 96: Error: Expected known function, got
>   'MATCH'

Is there an alternative I could use instead of `MATCH`? At the moment (just so I can do basic testing) I'm using LIKE, but it doesn't work too well if it's more than one word being used to search with.

**EDIT:**
This is how the code is used within the code:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $wckeyword = '%'.$skeyword.'%';

    $dlcresult = $em->createQuery('
        SELECT dlc.title, dlc.description, dlc.keywords
        FROM ShoutMainBundle:Dlc dlc
        WHERE MATCH (dlc.title, dlc.description, dlc.keywords) AGAINST (":keyword" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
        AND dlc.type = (":audio")
        ORDER BY dlc.date DESC'
    )->setParameters(array('type' => $stype, 'keyword' => $wckeyword));

    $dlcres = $dlcresult->getResult();
```

Comment: What are you using to call your queries? Please post a code sample of how you're quering the MySQL server.

Comment: Just edited my question with it

Comment: maybe this would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238814/problem-with-match-against-in-doctrine

Comment: @tawfekov that's for doctrine 1.x. Maybe this will help you a bit more: http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/69d1f293e8000a27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible with Doctrine2 ORM. As Doctrine supports many different database vendors and most of them don't have a `FULLTEXT` search feature, it's not supported at all.

You can always use [Doctrine2 DBAL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/dbal/2.0/en/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html) for searching. You lose all these nifty orm features, but in my practice they aren't that needed in searching situations anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Doctrine doesn't support that out-of-the-box, true. But you can:

- [Create custom functions for DQL yourself](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#adding-your-own-functions-to-the-dql-language)
- [Use native SQL and custom hydration](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/native-sql.html)